# SQLITE Edge detection

Tags: sqlite, rows, edge-detection

I have a given SQLIt database (so no chance to do it in a better way):

```
CREATE TABLE `history` (
    `TIMESTAMP` TIMESTAMP,
    `DEVICE`    `enter code here`varchar(32),
    `TYPE`  varchar(32),
    `EVENT` varchar(512),
    `READING`   varchar(32),
    `VALUE` varchar(32),
    `UNIT`  varchar(32)
);
```

In this table I have for example the following data:

```
DEVICE VALUE
d1     1
d5     500
d2     10
d1     2            <--
d5     501
d1     100          <---
```

I want to figure out for the device "d1" all timestamps where the difference between the last value and the current value is > 10

I have absolutly no idea how to do this with SQL

thank you

Comment: Are you on a decent OS, or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

To get the last value for the current timestamp T, you would use a query like this:

```
SELECT Value
FROM History
WHERE Device = '...'
  AND Timestamp < T
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You can then use this as a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) in your query:

```
SELECT Timestamp
FROM History
WHERE Device = 'd1'
  AND ABS((SELECT Value
           FROM History AS last
           WHERE Device = 'd1'                    -- or Device = History.Device
             AND last.Timestamp < History.Timestamp
           ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
          ) - Timestamp) > 10;
```

Comment: Nice solution! I think you maybe need a `WHERE device = "d1"` or some such.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks!